# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

the result of using default routing in asp.net mvc and using ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("title", "Index", "Question", new { id = 25}, null)
```

is :

```
http://localhost/question/index/25
```

for changing the link to

```
http://localhost/question/25
```

I've added new routing roles in Global.asax before default :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "default2", // Route name 
            "Question/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Questions", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I have the same Issue for **users , tags , ....** , Should I create the same role for each of theme ?

Comment: Where did you add the route? If you added it BELOW the default MVC route for {controller}/{action}/{id} you need to move it to above the default route. Also, you can't have two routes with the same name so i suggest calling this route "Questions" or something.

Comment: @NickBork , you Right . I added this route before `default` . and the name is different ( post updated )

Comment: So did moving the route location cause the ActionLink to generate the correct actionlink code? If so you could either create two additional routes, one for "Users" and one for "Tags" OR you could modify your new route and use Route Constraints to do some filtering to match only "Questions", "Users" or "Tags"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "", 
      "{controller}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
  );
```

**UPDATE:**

If the `id` is always going to be an integer then you can put a simple numeric constraint in the above route to avoid the routing issue reported by @Nick.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "my-route",
      "{controller}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new { id = @"\d*" }
  );
```

Comment: yes , I tried that. but I think this route directly affect to `forms` . I don't know why but `action` property of forms are **empty** when I using this route!!!!

Comment: If you use this route the default route for  {controller}/{action}/{id} would never match because your new route would ALWAYS be a match and every URL would look for the Index action. In order for this route to work you would need to create a route constraint to ensure that ID was valid (either a numeric value or that it exists in the database).

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would take this one step further and show you how to create a route constraint so you didn't need to register three seperate routes.

Using the following article as a guide you can create a constraint that will validate the current routes Controller against a list of controllers you will specify:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

So here is my class with the route constraint:

```
public class ControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string[] _controllers;

    public ControllerConstraint() : this(null) { }
    public ControllerConstraint(string[] controllers)
    {
        _controllers = controllers;
    }

    #region IRouteConstraint Members
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string  currentController = values.ContainsKey("controller")?  values["controller"].ToString() : null;

        return _controllers != null //The list of controllers passed to the route constraint has at least one value in it
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentController) //The current route data has a controller in it to compare against
            && (from c in _controllers where c.Equals(currentController,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select c).ToList().Count > 0; //We find a match of the route controller against the list of controllers
    }
    #endregion
}
```

From there all you need to do is modify how you register your route in the Globa.asax

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      "Action-less Route", // Route name
      "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Questions", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}, //Parameter defaults
      new {isController = new ControllerConstraint(new string[] {"Questions","Users","Tags"})} //Route Constraint
        );
```

You could also take it a step further and validate that {id} was a number with an additional route constraint like the following:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs